# Why does this Java 8 type inference fail?

Tags: java, java-8, type-inference

Why does the following code,

```
CompletionStage<Optional<String>> future = completedFuture(Optional.empty());
future.thenApply(optStr -> {
  return optStr.map(s -> s.length())
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string"));
});
```

fail to compile with,

```
unreported exception X; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Passing an explicit type argument of `IllegalArgumentException` to `orElseThrow` works.

Comment: I confirm that it does not compile with JDK 1.8.0_51 but Eclipse Mars 4.5.1 compiles it fine... Yet another difference between the two.

Comment: Yeah, yet another type inference bug. You can simply work-around using `.<IllegalArgumentException>orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string"))`